# How to do transparency with rounded filled rectangles in SWT?

Tags: java, graphics, swt

I'm using the SWT 4.2 `Tree` widget. I need to associate color codes with each `TreeItem` in the list. I'm doing this using `TreeItem`'s `setImage(...)` with images created as follows:

```
private Image createImage(int imageSize)
{
    Image image = new Image(Display.getDefault(), imageSize, imageSize);
    GC gc = new GC(image);
    gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
    gc.setBackground(... a Color object ...);
    gc.fillRoundRectangle(0, 0, imageSize, imageSize, 5, 5);
    gc.dispose();
    return image;
}
```

That actually works great, except for one detail: the corners *outside* the rounded rectangle are not transparent—they remain white. The effect is a rounded color square with white fringes. This is especially apparent when the user selects items in the `Tree`, because the selection color makes the white corners quite visible.

I've tried using `Image.setBackground(...)` before creating the `GC`, because the documentation for that method states: *"Sets the color to which to map the transparent pixel"*. However, setting the color to either white or the color of the `TreeItem` where the image is set (which happens to be white anyway) has no effect as far as I can see. I also tried setting the alpha value of the `GC` in the code above, but cannot seem to get the right incantation to set the background of the GC to transparent yet have the filled rectangle *not* be transparent.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I make the area outside the filled rectangle transparent, so that the corners of the image outside the filled rounded rectangle are properly transparent when they appear in the `Tree` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like "Color to alpha/transparency" which many photo editing tools can do:

Read this article if you want further details: [Taking a look at SWT Images](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#Transparency)

Something like this should work:

```
ImageData data = yourImage.getImageData();
// Assuming the corners are white
int whitePixel = data.palette.getPixel(new RGB(255,255,255));
data.transparentPixel = whitePixel;
Image transparentImageCorners = new Image(display, data);
```

If you are worried that this might affect colors that are contained in the image you draw, color the background first with a distinct color that you know isn't contained in your image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This may not have been sufficiently clear, but I'm not actually using an external image; the code (the original snippet) just creates an image object from scratch and then paints into it.  However, it seems like I should still be able to apply your approach, simply by creating two images. So I tried that, but unfortunately, it does not seem to make a difference: once set in a TreeItem, the colored square still does not have transparent corners.  I posted my code [here](http://pastebin.com/KTQqUu4e).

Comment: @mhucka That's exactly what I meant. I said image, because it's an `Image` you are using. Create the second `Image` _after_ you used the `GC` to paint the image, otherwise it will not work, because the `ImageData` does not contain what you paint until you actually paint it...

Comment: _@baz_ Now I understand. And it works! New code [here](http://pastebin.com/LzEXahxF).  The one issue is that, due to anti-aliasing, the corners outside the rounded rectangle are not actually white.  I need to figure out the correct color for the transparent pixel, but that's a separate issue. Anyway, thank you!